# "Undefined Index" error

Tags: php

I made it so that users could check 'remember me' on a login form and it would set cookies. Now if they logout it directs them to logout.php and the cookies should be deleted. It all works except i get these error messages.

> **Notice:** Undefined index: username in C:\xammp\htdocs\mine\logout.php on line 6
>
> **Notice:** Undefined index: password in C:\xammp\htdocs\mine\logout.php on line 7

My code for logout.php is

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], false, '/');
    setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], false, '/');
    session_destroy();
    echo "You've benn logged out. <a href='index.php'>Click here</a> to return.";
} else {
    die ('You are not logged in!');
}
```

Comment: Using `false` as third parameter will not clear the cookie, it will be registered as `0` which makes the cookie live until the end of the session. Use a time in the past, e.g. `time()-3600`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:''` instead of `$_POST['username']`

And `isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:''` instead of `$_POST['password']`

---

See: [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

If your users want to log out, it's unlikely that they have also submitted their username or password to the logout page, so `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` will be empty, hence the error you get.

However, you don't need to know the values (actual username or password) in order to unset the cookie, you just need to know the keys (which is 'username' and 'password', literally).

```
<?php
session_start();
setcookie('username', '', time()-3600, '/');
setcookie('password', '', time()-3600, '/');
session_write_close();
header("Location: /");
?>
```

That will log them out and redirect them to your frontpage.

Comment: This will not clear his cookies, which is his mentioned method of verifying a logged in user

Answer (score -1):

This is because the `$_POST` superglobal hasn't got the `username` and `password` variables.

I'd hazzard a guess that when you link from index.php to logout.php you aren't POSTing to logout.php (hence this call won't have the POST variables).

What you need to do is save the username and password in you session (or other form of persistent storage):

index.php after session_start();

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Then in logout.php you may be able to clear those values by using the `$_SESSION` superglobal instead of the `$_POST`.

Incidentally, I don't really know why you'd be setting the username and password as cookies, but that's besides the point of your question.